# How to call a function after sent the response in node js

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

After download the Zip file I need to call another function to ProcessZip  file. But am unable to trigger the function `ProcessZipFile()` after the `.send()`:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  DownloadZipFile();
});


function DownloadZipFile() {

    var file = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/student.tar.gz');

    s3.getObject(params
.on('httpData', function (chunk) {

    file.write(chunk);

   })
.on('httpDone', function () {

    file.end();

   })
.send();
   }

function ProcessZipFile() {
     //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't call functions after you send a response to the browser. Because the route is finished. I have 2 ideas for you.

1: Make your `DownloadZipFile()` as a middleware and at success you go to `ProcessZipFile()` and then send the response()

2: Make a new route where you call `ProcessZipFile()` and call this route from the frontend via ajax for example

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is designed to be [non-blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/), which means most I/O operations are asynchronous. You cannot simply call `ProcessZipFile()` after the `.send()` because this will trigger `ProcessZipFile()` **before** the download completes. Instead, you should call the function inside the `success` event handler which will be executed when the download completes.

```js
function downloadZipFile(s3Params, downloadPath, callback) {
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath);
  s3
    .getObject(s3Params)
    .on('httpData', function(chunk) {
      file.write(chunk);
    })
    .on('success', function() {
      // download succeeded -> execute the callback to proceed
      callback(null);
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      // download failed -> execute the callback to notify the failure
      callback(err);
    })
    .on('complete', function() {
      // close the file regardless of the download completion state
      file.end();
    })
    .send();
}

function processZipFile(filePath, callback) {
  // Process the file
  // Remember to call `callback` after completion
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const s3Params = { ... };
  const filePath = './tmp/student.tar.gz';

  downloadZipFile(s3Params, filePath, function(err) {  // this callback function will be executed when the download completes
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send('Failed to download the file.');
    } else {
      processZipFile(filePath, function(err) {  // this callback function will be executed when the file is processed
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send('Failed to process the file.');
        } else {
          res.send('File is downloaded and processed.');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can notice the "[callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)" created by the nested callback functions. To resolve the problem, you can [use `async` library or `Promise`](https://ciphertrick.com/2016/06/12/avoiding-callback-hell-node-js/), or [`async/await`](http://rossboucher.com/await) feature in ES7.

Comment: If the situation is like - I want to return the status as "successfully received the file" and then process the file asynchronously and update my DB. But I don't want to send any response after processing the file.

Comment: Then you simply call `res.send('successfully received the file')` before calling `downloadZipFile()`. Be aware that you should also remove the `res.send` inside the downloadZipFile's callbacks.